# RoR/Heroku : detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sqlite

I've got a problem when I try this command : git push heroku master

My error message is like that :

! Failed to install gems via bundler

! Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.

! https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

I've been trying everything I could find on StackOverflow about Gemfile modification.

Do you have any idea how i can solve my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is a read-only filesystem, so you'll likely have issues using sqlite3 on Heroku anyway.

I'd recommend switching over to Postgres as that is Heroku's native database, and you'll find that you'll likely run into far fewer problems if you use Postgres.

To do this, remove the `sqlite3` gem from your Gemfile and add:

`gem 'pg'`

**Update**

[Here are Heroku's docs on sqlite](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) but you'll note that the database essentially runs in memory, and is unique to each dyno on Heroku, which clearly can cause integrity problems.  I strongly recommend you migrate to Postgres, especially if you intend to use Heroku long term.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I've already tried this, and it didn't work ...
Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: That's odd.  Did you fully walk through setting up Postgres?

Comment: Yep, I followed this : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
But I had a problem when I tried to run this command : rake db:create.
My error message is :  "could not connect to server: Connection refused <0x0000274D/10061> Is the server running on host "localhost" <127.0.0.1>  and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432 ? "
And my server is actually running.

Comment: So, you're having this problem locally?  Did you install postgres?

Comment: Yep postgres is installed.

Comment: After i run `rake db:create` it gives me another error before aborting "fe_sendauth : no password supplied"